# jQuery & PHP to delete a file

Tags: php, jquery

Got this following code:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="deleteFile" id="'.$entry.'">Delete</a>
```

JS:

```
$('.deleteFile').click(function(){
    if (confirm("Delete file ?")){
      $imagefile = $(this).attr('id');
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
              action: 'deleteFile',
              imagefile: $imagefile,
          },
          url: 'assets/php/deleteFile.php',
          success: function(msg) {
              alert($imagefile);
          }
      })
    }
})
```

PHP:

```
if($_POST["action"]=="deleteFile") {
    $imagefile = $_POST['imagefile'];
    unlink("files/1/".$imagefile);
}
```

I do not why it does not work. My file is still here...

Could you please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tested to confirm `unlink()` works correctly? have you tested that the correct value is being passed to `$_POST['imagefile']`?

Comment: Double check the value you are sending to the server.  It appears your id value is incorrect as mentioned above.

Comment: It was just a permissions problem. Thanks a lot for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `echo $entry` variable here

```
<a href="#" class="deleteFile" id="<?php echo $entry; ?>">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
 <a href="#" class="deleteFile" id="<?=$entry?>">Delete</a>
```

PHP

```
 unlink($SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/files/1/".$imagefile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the php declaration before writing a php variable:

```
<?php echo $entry ?>
```

Your html code must look like:

```
<a href="#" class="deleteFile" id="<?php echo $entry ?>">Delete</a>
```

You need to save the file as php.